# Erlang: Get the first element of each tuple in a list

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, tuples, list-comprehension, erl

I can get the first element of every tuple if I create the list at the same time, for example

```
[element(2,X) || X <- [{1,2},{3,4}]].
[2,4]
```

This works as it should.
I want to be able to create the list before I try to do anything with it

**Ex: Create the list**

```
X = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5}]. 
[{1,2,3},{3,4,5}]
```

**Then get the first element of each tuple**

```
element(1,X).
```

But I get the error

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  element/2
        called as element(1,[{1,2,3},{3,4,5}])
```

I want this code to give the same results that my first example gave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [List Comprehension](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-10.0/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html) with a generator(<-)

```
X = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5}].
[A || {A,_,_} <- X].
```

This is saying that we want to print element `A`, where A is taken from the tuple `{A,_,_}`(a tuple which we generate from each tuple in X). Because we are only selecting A and don't care about the second and third element, they are set equal to _.

---

**Output**

```
1> X = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5}].
[{1,2,3},{3,4,5}]
2> [A || {A,_,_} <- X].
[1,3]
```